# Passing a variable to jQuery DateTimePicker for formating?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin [DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to format a DateTime varabile but I can't figure out how to apply the formatting command to a variable. All the examples I find are how to apply it to a DOM element which will not work for me. Does anyone know how to do this? The last code snip I have from my hours of trying things out is

```
obj.colModel[9].render = function (ui)
{
    var cellData = new Date(ui.cellData);
    return $.datetimepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss" }, cellData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by the creator at https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/862 the code to do this is:

```
var dateObj = new Date(ApprovalDate);
var dateStr = $.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", dateObj );
var timeStr = $.datepicker.formatTime('HH:mm', { hour: dateObj.getHours(), minute: dateObj.getMinutes() }, {});

var dateTimeStr = dateStr +' '+ timeStr;
```